# Marketing Cloud, Query for Click Data for an Email by EmailName

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

How would I go about creating a query for click data for an email by the email name. I've done this before using the JobID but i'm trying to automate this but haven't found a way.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Basically you have to determine: Which Data View holds the email name? We will need to connect this Data View with the _Click which holds the Click data. Then, what field is common in these two Data Views that can be joined in a query? Once you know that your query is halfway there. Documentation is very useful: https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_click/

Comment: Thanks AnonWonderer. This is very helpful. I thought that the email would be common in both cases but that was incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make this work by doing the following:

Create a DataExtension for your click data to go into using the _Click View table structure: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_click/

Depending on your account, you may need to change datatype BIGINT to TEXT (I did).

The EmailName value is found in the _Job table: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_job/

Create a Query Activity to select the data based on EmailName:

```
SELECT
c.*
FROM _Click c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
    JobID
    ,EmailName
    FROM _Job 
) j ON j.JobID = c.JobID
WHERE j.EmailName = 'Your Email Name Here'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for @Cameron. My next step now will be to automate this for finding click data and sending to those users that clicked.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help Gen,